# Range of datatypes in C

Tags: c

I was experimenting in C about the range of different datatypes and I stumbled into this problem. We know that the max value of int datatype is 2147483647. So I tried to assign a larger value to the int data type which was 21474836481234. It was way larger number than the maximum value of stored in int datatype. So when I printed the the output which came as "1234". I didn't understand how this number was printed. Can anyone explain to me? Thank You!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void main()
{
    int a;
    a=214748364812323;

    printf("a= %d",a);
}
```

Comment: And what output did you expect? Didn't you get a ccompiler warning?

Comment: You seem to understand there is a max value that an `int` can store (generally `int`s are 4 bytes on most systems). Providing a number larger than this max value will clearly have some unanticipated results. I believe this may come down to undefined behavior as far as C is concerned, but what likely happened is multiple bytes of the number `21474836481234` are stored outside of the `int`'s 4-byte boundary, so you're only printing the last few digits in this case.

Comment: Note that, if you use a debugger such as `gdb`, you can see for yourself where and how the data is stored in memory! This should illuminate the behavior you are observing.

Comment: "We know that the max value of int datatype is 2147483647." --> No. The range of `int` is [INT_MIN...INT_MAX]`.  It various from system to system.

Comment: @DavidGrayson While it's true that the code doesn't match the text of the question, that's not the crux of the question. The OP is clearly wondering why none of the digits above `1234` (according to the text) or `3032` (according to the code) get displayed. I don't think that difference merits closing.

Comment: It's confusing that you are asking about one number in the text of your question, and then using a different number in your code, and the numbers look very similar at first glance.  It makes it harder than necessary to provide good answers to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It was way larger number than the maximum value of stored in int datatype . So when I printed the the output which came as "1234".I didn't understand how this number was printed.

The hexadecimal representation of `21474836481234` is `0x1388000004D2`, which means that the low 32 bits is `000004D2`, i.e. `1234` in decimal. When you assigned `0x1388000004D2` to a type that can only store 32 bits, it's the low 32 bits that get stored, so you end up with `000004D2`.

Try doing the same thing with a smaller type. `char` is only 8 bits, so try storing a larger value like `0x10A` and you'll see that the resulting value is only `0x0A`.

Comment: "When you assigned 0x1388000004D2 to a type that can only store 32 bits, it's the low 32 bits that get stored"  --> That is often what happens, but C does not specify that behavior.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Fair enough, but I think OP was wondering how their result actually happened, not what the standard says or doesn't say is supposed to happen. Aside from problems with endianness, I don't think I've ever seen a C compiler keep the high bits and truncate the low ones, even if the standard technically allows it.

Comment: I have not seen keeping the high bits either, yet that is not the only other possibility.  I have seen capping, so `a` would have the value of 2147483647.  It is implementation defined.

Answer (score 1):

When given an out of range value for a signed type, "the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."

[This setup](https://godbolt.org/z/EEqeh776r) gets `1234` for `21474836481234` and `12323` for `214748364812323`. These are the `int` values produced by treating the least significant 32 bits of the inputs as `int` values.

---

> max value of int datatype is 2147483647

That may be true for your program, but it's not true in general. The standard only guarantees that the range will be at least -32,767 .. +32,767 and at least the range of a `signed short int` (and of a `signed char`).

The Wikipedia page about [C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) is quite good.

Answer (score 1):

> So when I printed the the output which came as "1234".I didn't understand how this number was printed. Can anyone explain to me?

`214748364812323` is a valid constant, yet outside OP's `int` range, perhasp it is `long` or `long long`.

Assigning that wider than `int` type to an `int` incurs:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is
> implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.  C17dr § 6.3.1.3 3

`a` took on some value.  OP reports `1234` for the constant `214748364812324` - That is valid C.  Often it is the lower bits of the value, but it may differ on other implementations.

---

Save time.  Enable all compilers warnings to be alerted to troublesome code like `int a; a=214748364812323;`

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behavior in c.  For fun I tried in gcc and got the following warning:

```
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:5:1: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
 a=214748364812323;
```

This is the compiler telling me that an overflow is occurring when trying to assign the value to `a`.

I get 12323 as the result.

Decimal 214748364812323 = 0xC35000003023. `int` on my system is 32 bits, so it looks like gcc only assigned the least significant 32 bits of the value 0x00003023, which would be typical overflow behavior.

Comment: It is not _undefined behavior_.  Converting an out of range value to an `int` results in implementation defined behavior.